# `bzr status` : hide unknown files?

Tags: version-control, bazaar

Is there a way to have `bzr status` ignore unknown files and only display the added/modified/deleted files?

I have checked `bzr help status` and the User Guide, and can not find a solution other than ignoring all of the unknown files with `bzr ignore`. Is there another solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you checked the help, you could have found `bzr status -V` easily. The `-V` parameter means that only files under version control are shown.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. Being new to this, It wasn't as obvious to me that this was what I was looking for on my first pass.